# Memory Leak in practical example

Tags: java, android, performance, memory, memory-leaks

I am constantly struggling with identifying memory leaks. I guess I have several memory leaks in my project [circular progress view](https://github.com/momentummodules/CircularProgressView).

One of my guesses is I have a memory leak in the internal class `FadeRunnable`. 
But to be honest I don't know exactly how to find out if this is exactly the source of the problem. Well, when I do the usual scenario and switch the orientation I see an increase of the memory usage as shown below. And if I comment out the usage of the `FadeRunnable` class the steps are smaller (*but still there, so I guess that's not the only leak*)

[image: memory steps]

Once I analyze the heap dump, I see something. But actually I don't know what the values mean. The things I do is

1. Change orientation many times
2. Open heap dump and sort by 'Retained Size'
3. Now when I click on "CircularProgressView' I see 8 rows in the right area. I guess this means there are 8 instances of the 'CircularProgressView' leaked and living somewhere as orphan in the memory.

**Is this correct? If so, how can I find out in the dump information (*I guess somewhere in the lower pane*) where this object is saved/held.**

[image: heap dump]

**I would love to have a step-by-step explanation how to find out if and which object is leaking some memory.**

All of the code of the suspected view can be found in this class.

https://github.com/momentummodules/CircularProgressView/blob/master/circularprogressview/src/main/java/momentum/circularprogressview/CircularProgressView.java

But also feel free to check out the full project for deeper insight and if you want to play around with it.

Thanks in advance!

## UPDATE

The code link from above shows the fixed code of the mem-leaking inner class. The following snippet shows the original mem-leaking code that should never be used like that

```
/**
 * Mem-leaking code, for fixed code see repository link
 * https://github.com/momentummodules/CircularProgressView/blob/master/circularprogressview/src/main/java/momentum/circularprogressview/CircularProgressView.java
 */
public class CircularProgressView extends View
{
    ...
    private Thread fadeThread = null;
    ...

    ...
    class FadeRunnable implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            ...
        }
    }
    ...

    ...   
    private void startFade(boolean fadeIn)
    {
        // check existing
        if(this.fadeThread != null)
        {
            // check if fade is already running
            switch(this.fadeThread.getState())
            {
                case TERMINATED:
                case NEW:
                    this.fadeThread = null;
                    break;
                case RUNNABLE:
                case BLOCKED:
                case TIMED_WAITING:
                case WAITING:
                    return;
            }
        }
        // create new
        this.fadeThread = new Thread(new FadeRunnable(fadeIn, this.fadeTime));
        this.fadeThread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to start from LeakCanary library: https://github.com/square/leakcanary. It's extremely easy to integrate and out of the box it will show you if you leak context.

Comment: Yep, use it already for my bigger projects. But actually I am interested in understanding the whole thing instead of relying on a 3rd party lib!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you do have a memory leak in `FadeRunnable` class.

Every instance of inner class contains implicit reference to its outer class, accessible through `OuterClass.this` operator. In your project, when you execute the `FadeRunnable` and then trigger reconfiguration by orientation change, the whole activity and your `CircularProgressView` contained within get recreated, but the `FadeRunnable` from previous is still alive (allocated) and, because of it holding implicit reference to its outer `CircularProgressView` class, the view continues to live also, that's why after several reconfigurations you have 8 instances of `CircularProgressView` allocated in memory, and that gets worse - every View keeps a reference to it's context, and this cannot be freed also, resulting in bad memory leaks.

Runnables, Handlers and similar objects that can out-live their enclosing activities, fragments, views etc. should be declared as standard classes or STATIC inner classes (a static inner class doesn't hold implicit reference to its outer class), and shouldn't keep references such as `Context`, `View` etc., instead you can keep a `WeakReference<>` so when your `Activity` is recreated through config change, the `View` can be destroyed and freed by garbage collector.

[This](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html) is a very informative article on the subject, I strongly suggest reading it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got that scenario. But do you have some link for general step-by-step memory leak analysis? I am interested in the way using the heap dump to find out that the `FadeRunnable` is the cause.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have the correct direction there. This `FadeRunnable` is certainly not cool. Even if you have other memory leaks, you defo should check this out.

In general what you should really be doing in a view is quite different, specially that views already have facilities to deal with timing and animation without the need for threads.

I'll suggest you what I believe is a simpler and cleaner approach to animate stuff on views.

- **Start by removing your runnable and thread completely.**

then to start an animation you do:

```
ValueAnimator animation = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
animation.setDuration(500);
animation.addUpdateListener(animationUpdate);
animation.addListener(animationUpdate);
animation.start();
```

and then you need those listeners

```
   // this gets called for every animation update,
   // inside this call you update `CircularProgressView.this.fadeAlpha`
   private final ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener animationUpdate = new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
      @Override public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
         // this fraction varies between 0f and 1f
         float fraction = animation.getAnimatedFraction();
         // ... do your calculation

         ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(CircularProgressView.this);
      }
   };

   // this is an optional one only if you really need
   // in that you get notified when the animation starts and ends
   private final Animator.AnimatorListener animationListener = new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

  @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
       // anything u need goes here
      ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(CircularProgressView.this);
  }

      @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) { 
      // anything u need goes here   
      ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(CircularProgressView.this);
      }
   };
```

and that's about it.

On the topic of actual memory leak analysis I'll suggest you to from now on and forever use the leak canary library: https://github.com/square/leakcanary it's a great tool to help us (developers) track memory leaks.

**edit:**

Why are you having a memory leak on this animation?
It's quite simple:

- on `startFade(boolean);` you create a new thread and a new runnable
- the runnable have a reference to the view (because it's an non-static inner class)
- the thread have a reference to the Runnable, so can run it.
- the framework destroy the view, because it's not part of the UI anymore (rotation, back button)
- the thread is still running, with the runnable still looping, with the View object still not destroyed because the Runnable references it.
- the view Object have an instance of `Context`, and this context is the `Activity`.

So at the end of this sequence your activity will not be garbage collected by the GC, AKA: Memory Leak !

Comment: Thanks for this approach for animating values. But regarding the memory leak, i use leak canary already in my other projects but would like to understand the whole memory leak story from the ground up

Comment: @martynmlostekk see my edit at the end of my answer.

Comment: one more question. can i use `postInvalidate`? Or what is the difference between `postInvalidate` and `postInvalidateOnAnimation`?

Comment: @martynmlostekk If you're doing an animation, meaning, it's a drawing on the screen that is changing overtime, on this specific case it's a fade-in/fade-out, you really should use `postInvalidateOnAnimation` with that the framework will only invalidate on the correct time for the animation frame to run smooth. This goes deep in the GPU driver and it's a very good optimisation that you should always take advantage of. On the other hand `postInvalidate` will try to run on the main thread as soon as possible, you should only use if it's not an animation.

Comment: @martynmlostekk as a last note. No, there's no step-by-step guide on memory leak. You have to really know and understand all the difference and nuances of what the GC is doing, what the framework is doing, diff on static and non-static inner classes (or annoymous inner classes) and apply this knowledge to ever step of your code.